# Is there a reliable way to get the selected element's names after applying an XPath expression with select-xml

Tags: .net, xml, powershell, xpath

I am struggling to find a reliable way to determine the names of elements that were selected by an XPath expression using the PowerShell cmdlet `select-xml`:

```
$xml = select-xml -content @'
<root>
  <A name='foo' localname='FOO'/>
  <B name='bar'                />
  <C id  ='baz' localname='BAZ'/>
  <D                           />
</root>
'@  -XPath '/root/*'

[System.Xml.XmlElement] $elem = $null
foreach ($elem in $xml.Node) {
   "name = $($elem.name), localname = $($elem.localname)"
}
```

This code prints

```
name = foo, localname = FOO
name = bar, localname = B
name = C, localname = BAZ
name = D, localname = D
```

Apparently, the XML attributes `name` and `localname` interfere with the .NET class attributes with the same names. So, is there a construct that returns `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` for the above example.

Comment: `$xml.Node.ParentNode`

Comment: How about `$elem.GetAttribute("name") / $elem.GetAttribute("localname")`?

Comment: @Ash, those return the value of the attributes, not the name of the Element.

Comment: Each property from an XMLElement class has a hidden `Get` method for it. So the node's built-in `name` property can be retrieved with `Get_Name()` in case of property name conflicts -> `$xml.Node.Get_Name()`. Likewise, `$xml.Node.Get_LocalName()` works too.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't quite clear as you were returning the values and then saying the names interfere with the .NET class attributes. @AdminOfThings has the right answer for getting the names of the elements. I think you can just use `$Elem.ToString()` too.

Comment: @AdminOfThings your second comment seems to be the solution I want (yet with `$elem.Get_Name()` in the `foreach` body). So, If you make this an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XMLElement class allows matching attribute names and XMLElement class property names. In that case, the attribute names take precedence during member access (`object.property`). The properties created when XMLElement object is instanced can be retrieved with `Get_` methods (`Get_Name()` and `Get_LocalName()` in this scenario). The attributes names can be retrieved with the `GetAttribute` method to ensure a consistent experience.

```
$xml = select-xml -content @'
<root>
  <A name='foo' localname='FOO'/>
  <B name='bar'                />
  <C id  ='baz' localname='BAZ'/>
  <D                           />
</root>
'@  -XPath '/root/*'
$xml.Node |% {
    # XMLElement class property Name and LocalName values
    "Name = {0}, LocalName = {1}" -f $_.Get_Name(),$_.Get_LocalName() 
    # Value of attributes name and localname
    "name = {0}, localname = {1}" -f $_.GetAttribute('name'),$_.GetAttribute('localname')
}
```